# Which tense of toward should I use?

Tags: tenses

Would I write this statement this way?   Would it be toward or towards?

"The puzzle piece shows how we fit together, working toward(s) a common goal."

Comment: *Towards* has no tense.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, the "s" is meaningless (it had meaning 1000 years ago).

Either one works fine; [*"towards"*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/towards) is supposed to be more British and [*"toward"*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/toward) more American, but both variants are used in both countries. [See Google Ngrams.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toward%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ctowards%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ctoward%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ctowards%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoward%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctowards%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoward%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctowards%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: +1 The first part is documented, fine. How do I know "but both variants are used in both countries"? And what of the Aussies; the others?

Comment: @Kris: Ngrams shows that both variants are used in both countries (with a reasonably high frequency). I don't know what Australia and India do.